# Nginx - access from a public ip address - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

An nginx server is up and running locally on my system[ubuntu 14.04]. But i am having difficulty accessing the same server from my public ip address, or from any other system using my public ip address. I have just started looking into nginx, its been great, but am stuck at this point now.

> Issue : Nothing displays when i use my public ip address in the
>   browser.

below is the config file "firstsite.com"

```
server {
        listen   80 default_server;
        server_name firstsite.com;

        root /var/www/uwsgiSite;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ index.html;
                allow all;
        }
}
```

which is available in "sites-available" and soft linked into "sites-enabled" folders. Also i have an entry in the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   firstsite.com
```

All the folders/files are available in /var/www with permission.

Later i would like to connect the same with a domain name [buy purchasing one] to my computer. For now, i am looking to make it work just with my public ip address, which is not working yet. Please guide me as to what is missing to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

There could be all kinds of things in the way - ISP, cable modem/router, software firewall on the system, etc... Can you provide details on how these are configured that makes you think you should be able to access the site from the public IP?

Comment: The server is running internally onn nginx and is accessible over the lan. Like if i use an ip as 192.168.1.x. I have also tried port forwarding on my router (netis WF2419) from my router address:1234 to 198.168.1.x:80. But no luck.. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please suggest

Comment: If it is accessible on the LAN then it is likely either your router or ISP. One way to debug this is to try accessing it from a computer you have access to that isn't on your LAN such as a free AWS instance. This will let you confirm if you are getting through your router by using telnet and other tools. I suspect it is your router or the IP:port you're typing into your browser aren't correct.

Comment: Well, I have tried to connect from a point external to LAN... I suspected the same thing as you suggested. I checked the IP and the port too. Still not able to access ... I understand that this might look vague and no reason to not work. But it is really killing me. .. Because I have dine port forwarding before successfully. But in this one. It just doesn't work . and I am not able to figure out what's missing.